# Blocking HTTP methods using HAPROXY

Tags: haproxy

How to construct HAPROXY configuration file to block requests for specific HTTP methods?

We're starting to see a number of attacks using methods that we do not support in our apps. We would prefer to reject the traffic at our load balancers rather than have our apps get bogged down with them.

Comment: Not a programming problem (but instead a sysadmin problem)

Comment: I modified the question to ask what I really wanted, which according to freedictionary.com is programming:  creating a sequence of instructions to enable the computer to do something.

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/mmalecki/npmjs.eu/blob/master/haproxy.cfg

Comment: http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try putting this in:

```
acl valid_method method GET HEAD
http-request deny if ! valid_method
```

this will deny any method that is NOT GET or HEAD. Change it to suit your needs

Comment: where should this be added?

Answer (score 1):

```
acl kill_it method TRACE
http-request deny if kill_it
```

Place this in the frontend section to explicitly deny the TRACE method.

Comment: Using "http-request deny deny_status 405 if kill_it" will actually send a "405 Method not allowed" instead of a "403 Forbidden"